# Triggering jquery ajax mysql insert using a gamepad

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, gamepad

This little project of mine involves registering actions associated with buttons pressed on a gamepad (PS3 style for the record). Because html5 supports gamepads I decided to use it as a fast and simple way for development.

The thing is, when running the ajax and the call of the php script, after pressing a button, the insert statement is duplicated. This not happens when I set *async: false* and use Firefox, but this goes against the purpose of ajax, and from what I've read, not an elegant thing to do.

This is what I have in my index.html (borrowed from here https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-the-html5-gamepad-api-to-add-controller-support-to-browser-games--cms-21345)

```
function reportOnGamepad() {
    var gp = navigator.getGamepads()[0];
    var html = "";
        html += "id: "+gp.id+"<br/>";
        html += "timestamp: "+gp.timestamp+"<br/>";

    html += "<br/>move<br/>"

    if (gp.buttons[0].pressed) { var moves=" B1"; $.ajax({
                url:'my.php',
                method:'POST',
                data:{
                    moves: moves
                },
            }); html+= " <br/>";
};
```

and my *my.php*

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$moves = $_POST['moves'];
if ($conn->connect_error) {
 die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$sql = "INSERT INTO test (moves) VALUES ('$moves')";
$conn->query($sql);
$conn->close();
```

Simple stuff as you can see. My knowledge of jquery/javascript is very basic so, if someone with more experience could point me what I'm doing wrong, I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The tuts+ tutorial you linked has some code to set up a polling interval for Chrome as a workaround for unreliability in the gamepadconnected event:

```
//setup an interval for Chrome
var checkGP = window.setInterval(function() {
  console.log('checkGP');
  if(navigator.getGamepads()[0]) {
    if(!hasGP) $(window).trigger("gamepadconnected");
    window.clearInterval(checkGP);
  }
}, 500);
```

[This bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=502824) is fixed in the latest version of Chrome and the workaround could be causing your issue.  For instance, if checkGP fires before the gamepadconnected event is received, you may register the reportOnGamepad interval twice.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So, the solution may have been in front of me the whole time...I will test it in a couple of hours and return with the results, for the record. But a part of the question remains, Firefox duplicates the insert in the database also, unless async is not set to false.

Comment: In the end I've decided to use python and evdev. Simpler and faster.